# Acessar o conteúdo do App_Data através da camada de negócio (ClassLibrary)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso carregar um arquivo que está na pasta `App_Data`, mas vi que não é possível utilizar o `Server.MapPath` na minha camada de negócio.

Qual abordagem é mais indicada para esse caso?

Adicionar a referência do `System.Web` na minha `ClassLibrary` e utilizar o `Server.MapPath` é viável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é viável, porque quem executa a *class library* é seu projeto web, mas procure usar da seguinte forma:

```
var appData= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/...");
```